# OrderBy numbers that are strings (cannot convert to int)

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, list

I'm trying to sort a `List<string>` that contains a list of elements that are each numbers followed by letters. This is why each element can not simply be converted to an int. The list generates at run-time, but for example, the list might contain elements such as:

```
10 dog, 53 cow, 2 crow, 29 horse, 12 rabbit, 107 frog, 35 cat, 7 dragon
```

I've tried sorting like this:

```
public void Compare()
{   
   sortedList = sortedList.OrderBy(g => g).ToList(); 
}
```

Results:

```
10 dog, 107 frog, 12 rabbit, 2 crow, 29 horse, 35 cat, 53 cow, 7 dragon
```

Clearly it is sorting alphabetically because in this example 107 came before 12 with the "10"in 107 being smaller than 12. But I need to sort it in a way that it would return in the order of the numbers preceding the word.

I need this example to return:

```
2 crow, 7 dragon, 10 dog, 12 rabbit, 29 horse, 35 cat, 53 cow, 107 frog
```

I'm pretty new to coding, and this has me completely stumped. Any suggestions on how I can achieve my desired results?

Comment: You need to separate the number from the word for sorting purposes. Is the word always going to be a single word? If so you can split the string by the space. However if you can have multiple words you need to find a way to reliably split it.

Comment: Though this is a simplified example that warrants a simplified solution, what you're looking for is commonly called "natural sorting". There's existing solutions out there for this, also handling things like varying number of numbers in the strings, varying positions, etc.

Comment: @lbanezowns , you should consider marking the answer that works as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can extract the data you want and then do the order by

```
var sorted = list
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Splited = x.Split(),
        Raw = x
    }) //split the string and keep the raw value
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Count = int.Parse(x.Splited[0]), // extract the number 
        Raw = x.Raw
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count) //order by that number
    .Select(x => x.Raw); //select raw value
```

Comment: And if OP needs to sort the original list he should call `ToList` and assign it to the original list-variable.

Answer (score 1):

### Use these lines for sorting:

```
List<string> L = new List<string> { "10 dog", "53 cow", "2 crow", "29 horse", "12 rabbit", "107 frog", "35 cat", "7 dragon" };

var sort = from s in L
           orderby Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(' ')[0]) 
           select s;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = lst.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split()[0])).ToList();
```

Comment: This one was also given I guess... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not was you asked for. I also see that there are many answer to do exactly what you asked for. **This is a suggestion**.

I don't know your system or anything but I think here by processing your object as string is an error. I'm pretty sure your system could benefit from having and object rather than this string representing your object. By creating a simple object even such as

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name{ get; set }
    public int Index{ get; set; }
}
```

You would gain type safety at many places. It would become easier to modify (in your current system try to add a third property such as Type ["Mammal", "Reptile", "Fish", etc.] and you will understand what I'm talking about). If you need to display that object as the string you have you can always override the `ToString()` of this object such as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", Index, Name);
}
```

Now when you would need to order or to do any manipulation on your object it become much simpler because you have a regular object not a string containing an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you've already identified, is that you cannot `OrderBy` the string. You want to sort the list on the numeric part, treated as a number.

We'll tell `OrderBy` to order on that part, by splitting the string on the first space, converting the first part `parts[0]` to an `int` and sort the list on that value.

No need to use `Select`, storing the original value and such. Just a simple `OrderBy` on the original `List`.

```
namespace SortListTest1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var animals = new List<string> { "10 dog", "53 cow", "2 crow", "29 horse", "12 rabbit", "107 frog", "35 cat", "7 dragon" };

            var orderedAnimals = animals.OrderBy(
                x =>
                    {
                        var parts = x.Split(' '); // split on first space
                        return int.Parse(parts[0]); // i.e. the numeric part, cast to an int
                    });

            foreach (var orderedAnimal in orderedAnimals)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(orderedAnimal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
2 crow
7 dragon
10 dog
12 rabbit
29 horse
35 cat
53 cow
107 frog
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of using List of strings use a dictionary. Your data structure looks like being in the form of key values.

```
Dictionary<int,string> Animals = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

Let the key part take the integer portion and let the string part handle name portion.

Then you can easily sort the data structure as below

```
sortedAnimalList = Animals.OrderByAscending(a => a.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using space as the separator, take the first value and convert it to in `int`:

```
sortedList = sortedList
    .OrderBy(g => Int32.Parse(g.Split(' ')[0]))
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a different approach: You have a list of (`count`, `name`) pairs (or (`id`, `name`) pairs), where `name` is your data object and `count` an quantifier.

1. Parse your data to split it into atomical values (in this case `int` and `string`)
2. Put the values into a designated structure that fits your needs (here it is simply the attribute `name`).
3. Assemble the data objects in a approriate container class (like `` List`1 `` or `` Dictionary`2 ``)
4. If it isn't sorted, sort it; you may need to let your data structure/class implement `` IComparable`1 ``/`IComparable` or define a custom `` IComparer`1 ``.

Here is what I came up with:

**Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var unsortedList = new List<string>() { "10 dog", "53 cow", "2 crow", "29 horse", "12 rabbit", "107 frog", "35 cat", "7 dragon" };
    var sortedList = new SortedList<int, string>((int)unsortedList.Count);
    foreach(var entry in unsortedList) {
        string[] frags = entry.Split(' ');
        if(frags.Length != 2) {
            throw new FormatException();
        }
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(frags[0]);
        string name = frags[1];
        sortedList.Add(count, name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("UNSORTED:");
    unsortedList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("SORTED:");
    foreach(var entry in sortedList) {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " " + entry.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
sortedList.OrderBy(g => int.Parse(g.Split(' ').First())).ToList();
```